# Prestashop get product attribute as per the csv and write them again on csv

Tags: php, prestashop, fgetcsv

I have a csv file. The file is like this

```
Product_id, Product_quantity
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
```

Now I have developed a module where it will get all those product quanity from the product id
and write them on the csv file without changinging any names

So for that I have my code is like this

```
Class GetProducts extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'getproducts';
        $this->tab = 'pricing_promotion';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'NewUser';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = 'true';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = $this->l('Get Products');
        $this->description = $this->l('lorem ipsum');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install() {
            $return = (parent::install() 
                && $this->registerHook('header'));
            return $return;         
    }

    public function uninstall() {
            if ( !parent::uninstall() )
                return false;
            return true;            
    }

    public function hookHeader() {
        $this->getProductQuantity();
    }

    public function getcsvUpdate() {
        $file = "http://localhost/projects/product.csv";
        $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($file,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
        $keys = array_shift($csv);
        print_r($keys); //getting csv headers

        $stock_array = array();
        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            fgetcsv($handle);

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $stock_array[] = $this->get_qty($data[0]);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        foreach( $stock_array as $stock ) {
            print_r($stock); //getting quantity and product id in array
        }

    }

    public function get_qty($id_product) {
        $product = new Product();
        $product_data[] = $id_product;
        $product_data[] = $product->getQuantity($id_product);
        return $product_data;
    }

}
```

You can see I have got the csv header and the array where I get the product id with its
quantity. So can someone tell me how to write those values to the csv
without deleting existing data in the csv? Any help and suggestions will be really
appreciable.

Comment: As per our knowledge, it is not possible to replace values or add data to an already existing CSV, but you can achieve what you want by getting all the data from your CSV to an array and then change/add values to that array and rewrite it to the same CSV.

Comment: @KnowbandPlugins can you share some codes that you are telling?